# nonblocking I/O behavior is weird for STDIN_FILENO and STDOUT_FILENO

Tags: linux, nonblocking

I have the following code:

```
void
set_fl(int fd, int flags) /* flags are file status flags to turn on */
{
    int val;

    if ((val = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0)) < 0)
        err_sys("fcntl F_GETFL error");

    val |= flags;       /* turn on flags */

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, val) < 0)
        err_sys("fcntl F_SETFL error");
}

int
main(void)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    set_fl(STDOUT_FILENO, O_NONBLOCK);  //set STDOUT_FILENO to nonblock
    if(read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZ)==-1) { //read from STDIN_FILENO
        printf("something went wrong with read()! %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I set `STDOUT_FILENO` to non-blocking mode but it seems the read operation on `STDIN_FILENO` finished immediately.  Why?

```
$ ./testprog
something went wrong with read()! Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Thanks

Comment: Mind checking the return value and errno to figure out why?

Comment: Was the program running in a pseudoterminal, or with I/O redirections, or what?

Comment: the errno is 11 , I run it in the terminal of ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's exactly right: doing a print of `errno` and a `perror` call immediately after the read results in a "resource busy" and an error number of 11, or `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`, as shown in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main (void) {
    char buf;

    fcntl (STDOUT_FILENO, F_SETFL, fcntl (STDOUT_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);
    fprintf (stderr, "%5d: ", errno); perror("");
    read (STDIN_FILENO, &buf, 1);
    fprintf (stderr, "%5d: ", errno); perror("");
}
```

which generates:

```
    0: Success
   11: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The reason is that file descriptors have two *different* types of flags (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Duplicating-Descriptors.html) in the section detailing duplicating file descriptors):

> You can duplicate a file descriptor, or allocate another file descriptor that refers to the same open file as the original. Duplicate descriptors share one file position and one set of file status flags (see File Status Flags), but each has its own set of file descriptor flags (see Descriptor Flags).

The first is [file descriptor flags](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Descriptor-Flags.html#Descriptor-Flags) and these are indeed unique per file descriptor. According to the documentation, `FD_CLOEXEC` (close on `exec`) is the only one currently in this camp.

All other flags are [file status flags](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Status-Flags.html#File-Status-Flags), and are shared amongst file descriptors that have been duplicated. These include the [I/O operating modes](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Operating-Modes.html#Operating-Modes) such as `O_NONBLOCK`.

So, what's happening here is that the standard output file descriptor was duplicated from the standard input one (the order isn't relevant, just the fact that one was duplicated from the other) so that setting non-blocking mode on one affects all duplicates (and that would probably include the standard error file descriptor as well, though I haven't confirmed it).

It's not usually a good idea to muck about with blocking mode on file descriptors that are duplicated, nor with file descriptors that will likely be inherited by sub-processes - those sub-processes don't always take kindly to having their standard files misbehaving (from their point of view).

If you want more fine-grained control over individual file descriptors, consider using `select` to check descriptors *before* attempting a read.

Comment: so all duplicate descriptors works like pointer right ?  they cannot have their own file status flags

Comment: @camino: as my 8yo son would say, correctamundo! (ie. yes). And I stress "duplicated" - files opened independently, with `open` for example, do not share file status flags with each other - that would be rather annoying to say the least.